# Login using email and password in CakePHP 2.1

Tags: authentication, cakephp-2.1

I know this question has been asked before, but I've gone through just about every article I can find on the internet and nothing has solved my problem -.-

I'm trying to get my CakePHP 2.1 app to login users using their email (instead of a username) and a password. Also, take into consideration that the controller I am using is called "Profiles", not "Users". Does that make any difference? Anyway, here's my code...

AppController.php

```
<?php
class AppController extends Controller {
    public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Auth'=>array(
            'authorize => array('Controller'),
            'Form'=>array(
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email'),
                'userModel' => 'Profile'
            )
        )
    );
}
?>
```

ProfilesController.php

```
<?php
class ProfilesController extends AppController {

    function login() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('You have been signed in.', 'flash_success');
                $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Login failed. Your username/password was incorect.');
            }
        }
    }

}
?>
```

login.ctp

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create();
echo $this->Form->input('email');
echo $this->Form->input('password');
echo $this->Form->submit('Sign In');
?>
```

Any ideas/suggestions why this login still isn't working!? I'm baffled.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for your answers! I've just solved my problem, which is actually a really easy mistake to make.

I was actually using:

```
'Form' => array(
    'userModel'=>'Profile',
    'fields' => array('username' => 'email')
)
```

by itself, INSTEAD of using it inside the 'authenticate' parameter like this:

```
'authenticate' => array(
    'Form' => array(
        'userModel'=>'Profile',
        'fields' => array('username' => 'email')
    )
)
```

Thanks for the help guys! Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Did you write this function ?

*ProfilesController.php*

```
function beforeFilter() {
     $this->Auth->fields = array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password');
}
```

Comment: Hey there :), thanks for getting back to me! I have that in my AppController.php, and I also just put it in my ProfilesController.php as well... still no difference. It keeps returning my "Login Failed" flash message!! Any other ideas?

Comment: "Login Failed" ? It could be a problem with the password...
Check the password's string sent by your form and the value in the database. Are they egals ?

Comment: Yep, the passwords are all good. I made 3 extra user accounts with my register form, and all of them are being hashed correctly. Still not logging in.

Answer (score 2):

check  the ans i gave to similar question

[unable to login in cakephp using different table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13491937/unable-to-login-in-cakephp-using-different-table/13492707#13492707)

get back if this does not solve

Comment: Hey mate. It didn't look promising at first, but your answer actually got my user logged in! Check my answer for why my login wasn't working. Really appreciate it, thanks man!!